# Allowing user to run prebuilt sql scripts

Tags: sql-server

This question is mostly asking about what would be the best method to accomplish my goal.

I have several sql queries written that I periodically run for the finance team at my work. These are select only queries that I copy the results into excel and send. The head of finance recently asked me if it were possible to allow him to run the reports and that got me thinking.

Is there a way for me to allow my co-workers to run these sql files that I have created without giving them all database access? The majority of these are very quick to run (0-10 seconds) and their aren't that many people to run them, so I'm not too concerned with performance.

One of the ideas that I thought of was creating a utility in Python but perhaps one of you fine people have a better idea or would recommend making the utility in another language.

All suggestions appreciated.

Comment: As much as I hate recommending VBA, since you're sending these out via Excel spreadsheet anyway, you could build an Excel macro that pulls the requisite data at the click of a button and distribute the macro to your coworkers.  That way you don't have external dependencies like python, etc.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Probably having it built into excel would be more user friendly and less work for me than creating an entirely new utility. I'll do some research into VBA and SQL SERVER but I'll leave the question open to further discussion for now. Thanks!

Comment: What about converting these queries into stored procedures and give access to execute them. You could also use SSRS for this.

Comment: In WinForms or WPF it would take about a few minutes to write such a tool. The results can be shown in a DataGrid in stead of excel. Dont know if thats good enough for these users. You can start in excell, but i guarantee this tool will get its own live and will grow... Maintenance is much more easier in Winforms or WPF

Comment: @LuisCazares In order to use SSRS, would I have to give them access to the report server?

Comment: @GuidoG I definitely thought of a .net solution but didn't know where to start. Always wanted to learn so if it's appropriate to use here I'll definitely check it out. Thanks for giving me somewhere to start researching.

Comment: Network access, yes. But you could limit the access to just the reports.

Comment: Why not create a simple website? You can control access to who uses the site, and the website can have the necessary permissions to run the scripts. In my experience, giving regular users access to the database is a nightmare. Your users will probably also appreciate the simple interface, and you can easily log who does what.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are "SELECT-only" queries, you could create VIEWs out of them, and give the users access to the views.

If they can type "SELECT * FROM MyView" they can [access the views directly in Excel](https://www.google.com/search?ei=DMl-XJb6EIWl_QbO3b7wBw&q=connect%20to%20sql%20server%20from%20excel&oq=connect%20to%20sql%20server%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i20i263j0l9.18598.21135..22262...0.0..0.118.1821.21j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i131j0i67.M61nKktpN_0).